# Can an alignment done wrong damage my ball joints

Tags: alignment, ball-joint

Alignment was done in 15 minutes., before the alignment car steered fine after the alignment car steered involuntary at times.

Answer (score 1):

it won't affect your ball joints.  However if your alighment was incorrectly done with "toe out" instead of a small "toe in" bias, then the car will catch and follow road grooves.

Answer (score 0):

There wont be any damage to ball joints. However, excessive camber can also cause tramlining. Or your alignment could have be off prior to the alignment, which caused uneven wear on your tires and is now causing the tramlining after having it properly aligned.

Comment: This is confusing- did you miss a few words?